# Jest shows 0 test of 2 total

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js

After the configuration of Jest with Node, I am able to run the tests with no errors but I am getting output like this

```
Test Suites: 0 of 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.508s
Ran all test suites.
```

even though I have a test file but it does not either make it fail or pass

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Config File

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "testMatch": [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)" ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["\\node_modules\\"]
}
```

Script

```
"test": "jest --config ./jest.config.json",
```

Command

```
npm run test
```

Jest Install command

```
npm install jest@22.2.2
```

How can I start getting the correct result?

Comment: Does your test file reside in the `/_tests_` directory?

Comment: Yes it resides in /__tests__ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this solution, make config file as .js extension.
**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    roots: ['./__tests__'], // provide path with reference to this modue, I assumed both are in root
  };
```

**script**

```
 "test": "jest --config='./jest.config.js'"
```

**sum.js**

```
function sum(num, num1){
return num+num1
}
exports.sum=sum
```

**__tests __/sum.test.js**

```
const sum = require('../sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum.sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
```